# Is there an equivalent of exec 5> / BASH_XTRACEFD="5" / set -x for busy box ash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04, busybox

I have a script that runs as expected in `bash` but when it's transferred to a box running `busybox` under the `ash` shell it doesn't do what I'd like.  I've written 2 simple scripts.  *myscript1.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 5> debug_output.txt
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
set -x
PS4='$LINENO: '

var1=blah
var2=foo

echo Currently in $0
echo
echo $0 :: var1 : $var1, var2 : $var2

export var1
echo
echo Entering myscript2.sh
./myscript2.sh
echo
echo Back in $0
echo $0 :: var1 : $var1, var2 : $var2
echo
```

and *myscript2.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Currently in $0
echo
echo $0 :: var1 : $var1, var2 : $var2

var1=flop
var2=bleh
```

I wrote them only to test the logging feature.  The first 3 lines of *myscript1.sh* creates a file called *debug_output.txt* and has the output of the script as it runs.  This is the output of *myscript1.sh*:

```
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~/bashscripttutorial$ ./myscript1.sh
Currently in ./myscript1.sh

./myscript1.sh :: var1 : blah, var2 : foo

Entering myscript2.sh
Currently in ./myscript2.sh

./myscript2.sh :: var1 : blah, var2 :

Back in ./myscript1.sh
./myscript1.sh :: var1 : blah, var2 : foo

(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~/bashscripttutorial$ ls
debug_output.txt  myscript1.sh  myscript1.sh~  myscript2.sh  myscript2.sh~
```

As you can see the log file *debug_output.txt* was created and here is the output:

```
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~/bashscripttutorial$ cat debug_output.txt 
+ PS4='$LINENO: '
8: var1=blah
9: var2=foo
11: echo Currently in ./myscript1.sh
12: echo
13: echo ./myscript1.sh :: var1 : blah, var2 : foo
15: export var1
16: echo
17: echo Entering myscript2.sh
18: ./myscript2.sh
19: echo
20: echo Back in ./myscript1.sh
21: echo ./myscript1.sh :: var1 : blah, var2 : foo
22: echo
(^)#(^)#(^)#(^)bminter@ubuntu:~/bashscripttutorial$
```

The thing to point out is that I can see exactly what's happening in the script and on what line number it's happening.  In *busybox* it's a different story.  Here's *myscript1.sh*:

```
# cat myscript1.sh
#!/bin/bash

exec 5> debug_output.txt
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
set -x
PS4='$LINENO: '

var1=blah
var2=foo

echo Currently in $0
echo
echo $0 :: var1 : $var1, var2 : $var2

export var1
echo
echo Entering myscript2.sh
./myscript2.sh
echo
echo Back in $0
echo $0 :: var1 : $var1, var2 : $var2
echo
```

and here's *myscript2.sh*:

```
# cat myscript2.sh
: cat myscript2.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo Currently in $0
echo
echo $0 :: var1 : $var1, var2 : $var2

var1=flop
var2=bleh
```

This is the output from running *myscript1.sh*:

```
# ./myscript1.sh
: ./myscript1.sh
+ PS4=$LINENO:
: var1=blah
: var2=foo
: echo Currently in ./myscript1.sh
Currently in ./myscript1.sh
: echo

: echo ./myscript1.sh :: var1 : blah, var2 : foo
./myscript1.sh :: var1 : blah, var2 : foo
: export var1
: echo

: echo Entering myscript2.sh
Entering myscript2.sh
: ./myscript2.sh
Currently in ./myscript2.sh

./myscript2.sh :: var1 : blah, var2 :
: echo

: echo Back in ./myscript1.sh
Back in ./myscript1.sh
: echo ./myscript1.sh :: var1 : blah, var2 : foo
./myscript1.sh :: var1 : blah, var2 : foo
: echo
```

*debug.output.txt* is created but it's an empty file.  Is there a way to get a similar output like I do on the `bash` side?

Comment: have you changed the 'shebang line' (line 1) to `#!/bin/sh` when you run it in busybox? (Not saying that will fix it). Good luck.

Comment: I did as you suggested and it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You try to use bash specific variable with ash, the shell of busybox, but this shell don't know them (LINENO and BASH_XTRACEFD).

When you call set -x , the trace is print on fd2 (standard error).

You don't seen that with bash because you tell to catch the output of set -x with BASH_XTRACEFD and you redirect this output on a file (debug_output.txt).

With busybox, you see the trace of set -x on the screen because the output of fd2 is not redirect on the file.

If you want to get this output on the file with busybox, you must redirect fd2.

```
exec 5> debug_output.txt
```

became

```
exec 2> debug_output.txt
```

I can't seen a way to replace the variable LINENO with ash but you can use anchor to remenber you where you are like :

```
echo Currently in $0>&2
```

at the start of myscript2.sh